# Windows Live Messenger for Mac?

Tags: windows, instant-messaging, windows-live-messenger, windows-live

I have a friend who uses a Mac, and was wondering if there is a version of Windows Live Messenger for Mac?  Or something comparable that uses/takes advantage of the Windows LIVE ID?  I'm interested in recommendations, as well as "is there a Mac version of Live Messenger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most complete instant messaging multi protocol client for mac : [adium](http://adium.im/)

There is also a [live messenger for mac](http://www.microsoft.com/Mac/products/messenger/default.mspx), but I think adium is far better.

Answer (score 0):

It's sometimes easier to use web based tools for this, such as [Meebo](http://www.meebo.com) or [eBuddy](http://www.ebuddy.com).

With all of these tools, I'd still be careful about giving Live credentials to any website (or app). Think of all the websites that you use this Live ID on, and whether someone can use your hotmail address to 'mail a new password' and compromise those accounts.